# Restart VM during Vagrant provisioning

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I am trying to setup vagrant + chef configuration.
One of provisioning actions requires me to change locales on the server.
When I change locales I must restart VM or relogin to that take effect.
Any idea if it is possible in Vagrant?

Comment: The hostname cookbook [restarts Chef](https://github.com/franco/chef-hostname/blob/master/recipes/default.rb#L68) to let the new hostname take effect, maybe that's a starting point.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a simple provisioner to be able to do just that.

https://gist.github.com/ukabu/6780121

This works for Windows Guest and the VirtualBox provider (could be adapted easily for other OSes or providers).

With it you can do :

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  # run list for stuff that needs to be done before a reboot
end
config.vm.provision :reboot
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  # run list for stuff that needs to be done after a reboot
end
```